# How can I write to System.in from node.js?

Tags: node.js, command-line, stdin

I'd like to pass input from node into a commandline-based program I wrote. Starting the program is easy enough with child_process.exec, but how can I pass more input after the program has been started?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`child_processes.exec` [returns a "ChildProcess object"](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), which has a property called `stdin`, which is a writable stream to that process's `stdin`. Check out [the docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdin) for more info.